# Empty Row Prevention in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting some blank data when inserting into MySQL database with PHP

My problem is

1. `Id- 1, name= A, sname= A, standard= A, category= A, address =123A, pincode= 123, email= A@gmail.com, mobile1 =1234567890`
2. `Id- 2, name= BLANK, sname= BLANK, standard= BLANK, category= BLANK, address =BLANK, pincode=0, email= BLANK, mobile1 =0`
3. `Id- 3, name= B, sname= B, standard= B, category= B, address =123B, pincode=123, email= B@gmail.com, mobile1 =1234567890`

This is PHP code

```
<?php
$Name=$_POST['name'];
$School=$_POST['school'];
$Standard=$_POST['standard'];
$Cate=$_POST['cate'];
$Address=$_POST['address'];
$Pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
$Email=$_POST['email'];
$Mobile1=$_POST['mobile'];  

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $sql="SELECT * FROM somename";
        if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result) + 15118;

            $sql1="INSERT INTO somename(Id,name,sname,standard,category,address,pincode,email,mobile1) VALUES('$rowcount','$Name','$School','$Standard','$Cate','$Address','$Pincode','$Email','$Mobile1')";
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
            {

            header("Location:file.php?id=$rowcount");
            }

        else 
        {
            echo "error msg";
        }
      }
    mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Comment: Set `not null` in table structure. Check for empty values before inserting in PHP

Comment: Use prepared statements. Currently, your code is prone to SQL injections.

Comment: Check if there actually are values longer than 0 coming through $_POST

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways:**

you can set `not null` from mysql from phpmyadmin.

Also you can use HTML5 `required` attribute from the your form.

Or you can use PHP's `empty()` to do this from php code.

And you can also use javascript or jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Which of those fields gives you a NULL input?

As  user dev-odedra already said you should set `not null` on the specific columns(to ensure these columns don't accept NULL entries), and at the same time use the `required` attribute in the form (to ensure it is impossible to pass empty value in the POST), but additionally you should check your values and see whether they match your predefined column types in the database table.